# How should i handle Rest services for 2 apps same database

Tags: android, rest, server

I have an application server running some rest services for management, filling the database and is all setup, but i also have an android app that only search through that database for 2-3 columns for each table. My question is, should i create two models in the same server? I mean like Model, repository, controller and assemblers for managing app and android app or, should i use only one and handle only the info i want in the android app. I think for security reasons there shouldn't be risks of info leaking.

Edit: Well i ended up creating Object and response/ObjectApp in my server for now to send data. Hopefully someone knows how to properly handle this and tell me if i did it right or if i should change it